# Get number of replacements

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace, numbers

Is there a method to get the number of replacements using `.Replace("a", "A");` ?

```
Example:

String string_1 = "a a a";
String string_2 = string_1.Replace("a", "A");
```

In this case, the output should be 3, because `a` was replaced with `A` `3` times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the count using [`.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) function :

```
 string_1.Split(new string[] { "a" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length-1;
```

After splitting the string we will get one item more. Because, `.Split` function returns a string array that contains the substrings in this string that are delimited by elements of a specified string array. So, the `Length` property's value will be **n+1**.

Comment: Why did you put `-1` at the end?

Comment: Length is always (O)1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this directly with string.Replace, but you could use the string.IndexOf to search for your string until it doesn't find a match

```
int counter = 0;
int startIndex = -1;
string string_1 = "a a a";
while((startIndex = (string_1.IndexOf("a", startIndex + 1))) != -1)
    counter++;
Console.WriteLine(counter);
```

If this becomes of frequent use then you could plan to create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
     public static int CountMatches(this string source, string searchText)
     {

        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText))
           return 0;

         int counter = 0;
         int startIndex = -1;
         while((startIndex = (source.IndexOf(searchText, startIndex + 1))) != -1)
             counter++;
         return counter;
     }
}
```

and call it with

```
int count = string_1.CountMatches("a");
```

The advantages of IndexOf are in the fact that you don't need to create an array of strings (Split) or an array of objects (Regex.Matches). It is just a plain vanilla loop involving integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Regex.Matches` method to find out what would be replaced. Use the `Regex.Escape` method to escape the string if it would contain any characters that would be treated specially as a regular expression.

```
int cnt = Regex.Matches(string_1, Regex.Escape("a")).Count;
```