# Count the string by words not char

Tags: c#, string, count, webbrowser-control

I am working on this code in which it can identify the word listed below from the Web Browser. Those words will turn into asterisk once they are identified and will count how many words were replaced but it didn't work. Someone can help?

Here is my code:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(txbAdress.Text);
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder(doc2.body.outerHTML);


        string query;
        query = @"
```

select Word from ListWords
";

```
        List<string> words = new List<string>();

        DataSet ds;
        DataRow drow;

        ds = DatabaseConnection.Connection1(query);
        int index, total;

        total = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

        string current_word;

        for (index = 0; index < total; index++ )
        {
            drow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[index];
            current_word = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();

            words.Add(current_word);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(query);


        Console.WriteLine("array:" + words);
        foreach (String key in words)
        {
           // String substitution = "<span style='background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);'>" + key + "</span>";

            int len = key.Length;
            string replace = "";

            for ( index = 0; index < len; index++)
            {
                replace += "*";
            }

            html.Replace(key, replace);
            //count++;
        }

        //Console.WriteLine("Total number of words: " + count);


        doc2.body.innerHTML = html.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: "but it didn't work" - can you explain how? Do you want to know how many words in `words` were matched, or how many words were replaced? Is "abc bobo bobo bobo test" 3 words or 1? What about "gagaotest"?

Comment: how many words were replaced

Comment: "abc bobo bobo bobo test" 3 bobo

Comment: Hi kyte, please edit your question with the additional details (describe *how* it's not working -> what is the input, what is the expected output, what is the actual output) rather than putting those details in the comments.

Comment: John, no words will get count because there's no 'gago'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get number of replacements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442221/get-number-of-replacements)

Comment: Sorry, I typo'd. "gagotest".

Answer (score 1):

Just count them before you replace them

**Given**

```
public int CountOccurrences(string source, string match)
{
   var pos = 0;
   var count = 0;
   while ((pos < source.Length) && (pos = source.IndexOf(match, pos, StringComparison.Ordinal)) != -1)
   {
      count++;
      pos += match.Length;
   }

   return count;
}
```

**Example**

```
var count = CountOccurrences(html,key);
html.Replace(key, substitution);
```